# How to use channels in go?

Tags: go

I have a function which takes an int array and dumps them in a channel.

```
func Dump(a []int, ch chan int) {
    for i := range a {
        ch <- i
    }
    close(ch)
}
```

This main doesn't build:

```
func main() {
    ch := make(chan int)
    arr := []int{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
    Dump(arr, ch)
    for i := range ch {
        fmt.Printf("Got %v\n", i)
    }
}
```

throws this error:

```
fatal error: all goroutines are asleep - deadlock!

goroutine 1 [chan send]:
main.Dump(0xc000078f48, 0x5, 0x5, 0xc00006e060)
        /Users/300041738/go-workspace/src/test.go:7 +0x43
main.main()
        /Users/300041738/go-workspace/src/test.go:15 +0x9b
exit status 2
```

However, this builds:

```
func main() {
    ch := make(chan int)
    arr := []int{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
    go Dump(arr, ch)
    for i := range ch {
        fmt.Printf("Got %v\n", i)
    }
}
```

Why do I have to write go infront of Dump? I don't wish to dump the contents of the array asynchronously.

Comment: "Doesn't build" isn't much of a problem statement. What exactly happens What error do you see?

Comment: Please Take the Tour of Go for such fundamental questions, then skim through the official Blog and the relevant Talks.

Comment: Think of a channel as a pipe with a certain length. You can't pump in arbitrary amounts of water on one end if nobody on the other end takes it out.

Comment: the first error does not mean the build has failed, it means the program is in an unrecoverable execution error state. Its a state you inadvertently created when you wrote on the unbuffered channel from the main thread. The channel blocks because it waits to be read from another thread. Because there is no such mechanism in the first version, the program ends in a panic. As demonstrated, using the go keyword allows to runs the function asynchronously. As a consequence the write operation happens in a different thread than the read operation, so everything completes fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The root of your problem - when you writing to unbuffered channel it's locked until someone read the value from the channel.
For unbuffered channel - after each write operation you have to do one read operation. Else your second write operation will be locked until someone read the first value. In your first example, it will never happen.

To illustrate:

1. `Dump()` function invoked
2. Running the first iteration of `for` loop
3. Write `i` value to the channel
4. Running the second iteration of `for` loop
5. Trying to write the next `i` value to the channel, but it locks, nobody has read the first value.
6. As all work is done in the single main goroutine the entire app is locked. Deadlock in the result.

This happens when adding the goroutine usage (`go Dump(arr, ch)`):

1. `Dump()` function invoked in the separate goroutine
2. Running the first iteration of `for` loop
3. Write `i` value to the channel
4. Running the second iteration of `for` loop
5. Trying to write the next `i` value to the channel, but it locks, nobody has read the first value.
6. Goroutine is locked (where we running `Dump()`), but we have the main goroutine and go scheduler switches the control to the main goroutine.
7. It means this line is actually executed `for i := range ch`. And it finally reads the first value!
8. Now `Dump()` goroutine is unlocked and it's possible to write the second value.
9. The control will be passed between two goroutines until all work is done.

Note, the exact order of execution can differ (based on the logic of go scheduler). To play with it, you can add print into `Dump()` function for the case with `go Dump(arr, ch)`:

```
func Dump(a []int, ch chan int) {
    for i := range a {
        fmt.Printf("Write %v\n", i)
        ch <- i
    }
    close(ch)
}
```

You will see that Write and Got messages will intermix.

It's hard to provide a solution for your answer because it's a sandbox example and the channel is not needed there in reality.

By using buffered channel, let's say with size `n`, you can do `n` writes without locking and reads.
I would recommend you to review the [basics of Go channels](https://tour.golang.org/concurrency/2).

Answer (score 3):

Channels have buffers. By default the buffer is of size 0. In other words, if an element is to be inserted to a non-buffered channel, the inserting goroutine will halt till another goroutine retrieves the value from the channel.

So for fun, try this :

```
import "fmt"

func Dump(a []int, ch chan int) {
    for i := range a {
        ch <- i
    }
    close(ch)
}

func main() {
    arr := []int{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
    ch := make(chan int, len(arr)) //specify channel buffer length equal to arr size
    Dump(arr, ch)
    for {
        i, ok := <- ch
        if ok {
            fmt.Println("received a number !", i)
        } else {
            fmt.Println("channel is closed, we're done here")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do I need to mention the buffer size if I don't wish to use the goroutine feature of Dump function? If I don't mention the len(arr) in make, then I must use the goroutine. Why? Isn't the channel getting appropriately closed after the function ends. Does that mean only channels can have undefined buffer only during asynchronous execution?

Comment: 1. A channel is never automatically closed. 
2. A channel has a buffer, if the buffer length is unspecified, it's zero.
3. Having 2 goroutines allows for blocking one goroutine as the other works.

Answer (score 1):

A dealock is caused because your main goroutine is trying to write to a channel but nobody is reading from it. You don't need to use buffered channels here.

There is a concept of pipelining in go. Your `Dump` function is basically acting like the source of the pipeline here. You can modify your `Dump` function to something like this:

```golang
func Dump(a []int) chan int {
  ch := make(chan int)
  go func() {
    for i := range a {
      ch <- i
    }
    close(ch)
  }()
  return ch
}
```

Notice I'm writing into the channel in a separate go routine now.